# how many occurrences of the substring in a string without any default functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to find how many occurrences of the substring in a string without any default functions in python and I'm not getting any value as output. please somebody help me to solve this problem.

```
s1 = input("Enter the String:")
ss = input("Enter the Substring:")
s2 = s1[::-1]
count = 0
n = 0
len = len(s1)

while (n < len):
    for i in s1[0+n::]:
        if ss in i:
            count = count + 1
        n = n + 1
n = 0
while (n < len):
    for i in s2[0+n::]:
        if ss in i:
            count = count + 1
        n = n + 1

print(count)
```

Comment: by substring you refer to words or can be anything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your sample input, your expected output and actual output.

Comment: `string.count(sub_str)`?

Comment: How do you define a "default function"?

Comment: How many occurrences of `aa` are in `aaaa` according to your definition?

Comment: Hint: `for i in s1[0+n::]:` will yield always one char. So if `ss` is more then one char your `if` will never be true

Answer (score 1):

Break this down into small problems.

You need to find all of the substrings of the correct length in your string.

```
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> ss = "el"
>>> [s[i:i + len(ss)] for i in range(len(s)-len(ss))]
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'o ', ' w', 'wo', 'or', 'rl']
>>> [sub for i in range(len(s)-len(ss)) for sub in [s[i:i + len(ss)]]]
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'o ', ' w', 'wo', 'or', 'rl']
```

Now, you need to filter out ones that equal the substring.

```
>>> [sub for i in range(len(s)-len(ss)) for sub in [s[i:i + len(ss)]] if sub == ss]
['el']
```

Now, if we find the length of that list...

```
>>> len([sub for i in range(len(s)-len(ss))
...          for sub in [s[i:i + len(ss)]]
...          if sub == ss])
1
```

We have the number of occurrences of the substring.